# Is it unusual for users with NTFS "write" but not "delete" permissions not to be able to modify files?

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions

I recently removed a user's NTFS "delete" permission (leaving them with full read/write access to a share), only to discover that they effectively only had read but not write access to their files.

What am I missing here? Is it not possible to grant "write" while denying "delete" access rights... and to have that reflected in a user's effective permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it might appear that they only have read access because many programs such as Word write to a temporary file and then delete the main file and then rename that temporary file to the main file. If the program can't delete the main file in order to replace it with the temporary file, they will fail to save and the main file will remain unchanged. This might cause the file share to appear read only in some cases such as that one when the delete permission is denied.

Comment: Aha! Good thinking. That's what it was.